# Unable to connect to remote Git repository

Tags: git, ssh

Trying to push to remote Git repository I receive the following error:

```
no such identity: /Users/Victor/.ssh/id_rsax: No such file or directory
```

What is id_rsax? It should be id_rsa, which is in place. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a ~/.ssh/config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This path has to be specified somewhere.

Check `~/.ssh/config`, or any file where you might have specified the SSH key, and inadvertently added `x` at the end of `id_rsa`.

Also read the [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/) about authenticating for more information.